# Ionic App and server post: Acces-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, .htaccess, cordova, post

I'm pretty new in angularJs, in my ionic app I try to send a json to my server, this is the controller:

```js
`enter code here`.controller('DashCtrl', ['$scope','$http',function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.sendForm = function(){
         
        $http({
        method  : 'POST',
        url     : 'http://www.---.org/appForm.php',
        data    : JSON.stringify($scope.formData),  // pass in data as strings
        headers : {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'}
        })
        .success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);

            if (!data.success) {
             // if not successful, bind errors to error variables
                $scope.errorName = data.errors.name;
                $scope.errorSuperhero = data.errors.superheroAlias;
            } else {
             // if successful, bind success message to message
                $scope.message = data.message;
            }
        });
    };
```

but when I send my post the console shows me this error message:

-[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin htt.. is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (appForm.php, line 0)

-[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load htt.. Origin `http://localhost:8100` is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (localhost, line 0)

I try to put this .htaccess in my home folder:

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"

but this add another error:

-Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error).

I'm going crazy! does anyone have any idea?!thanks a lot for the attention

Comment: Is there any stacktrace error in your server's log? Error 500 is a server error.

Comment: Have you tried to change the settings in the `config.xml` file `<access origin="*"/>` located in your android project.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a service proxy to your `ionic.project` file.

```
{
  "name": "appname",
  "email": "",
  "app_id": "",
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/v1",
      "proxyUrl": "https://api.instagram.com/v1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Check the relevant part in https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli

Answer (score 0):

open command line get to chrome directory in my case:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application

type : `chrome.exe --disable-web-security`

in your brower go to `http://localhost:8100` , and your problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

Cross origin is an issue that we need to explicity handle in ionic framework, during development phase.

[Here is a good blog page](http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/) from ionic team that contains complete details of the problem

On a high level:

Step 1 : Add proxy details to ionic.project

```
{
 "name": "proxy-example",
  "app_id": "",
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api",
      "proxyUrl": "http://cors.api.com/api"
    }
  ]
}
```

Step 2 : As a good practice, add angular constant to manage external endpoints - This is not mandatory

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])
.constant('ApiEndpoint', {
  url: 'http://localhost:8100/api'
})
```

Step 3: Restart "ionic serve". Without restarting ionic.project changes will not take effect.